# How to draw a graph with python?

Tags: python, graph, graph-visualization

I need the program to draw a graph like the one in the picture. How to make the square into four parts? How to write text on the arrows?
[image]

I tried to make a circular graph, but unfortunately it didn't work because it doesn't allow to divide the circle into four parts

Comment: Have you thought about using LaTeX?, This could be done with Tikz quite easily

Comment: What you're looking for is a special case of a tree graph. Check out this module that focuses specifically on tree graphs: http://etetoolkit.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a comment in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304488/how-to-draw-a-graphic-like-the-one-in-the-picture-with-python), but here's an example that starts building up the network that you picture using Matplotlib's [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) patch, [`arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow) and [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) functions which you can then build up from.

```py
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def draw_2x2_grid(ax, xy, bwidth=0.25, bheight=0.25, numbers=[]):
    """
    Draw a 2x2 grid of squares with numbers in each box.
    """

    for i in range(2):
        x = xy[0] + i * bwidth
        for j in range(2):
            y = xy[1] + j * bheight
            
            r = Rectangle((x, y), bwidth, bheight, facecolor="none", edgecolor="k", lw=3)
            ax.add_patch(r)
            ax.text(
                x + bwidth / 2,
                y + bheight / 2,
                str(numbers[i * 2 + j]),
                va="center",
                ha="center",
                fontsize=20,
            )
            

def draw_arrow(ax, xystart, xyend, textabove=None, textbelow=None, arrowkwargs={}):
    """
    Draw and annotate an arrow between two points.
    """
    
    # get displacements dx, dy
    dx = xyend[0] - xystart[0]
    dy = xyend[1] - xystart[1]

    angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(dy, dx))

    ax.arrow(xystart[0], xystart[1], dx, dy, **arrowkwargs)
    
    # add text
    if textabove is not None:
        ax.text(
            xystart[0] + dx / 2,
            xystart[1] + dy / 2,
            textabove,
            ha="center",
            va="bottom",
            transform_rotates_text=True,
            rotation=angle,
            rotation_mode='anchor',
            fontsize=12,
        )
        
    if textbelow is not None:
        ax.text(
            xystart[0] + dx / 2,
            xystart[1] + dy / 2,
            textbelow,
            ha="center",
            va="top",
            transform_rotates_text=True,
            rotation=angle,
            rotation_mode='anchor',
            fontsize=12,
        )
            
# width and height of each subbox within a 2x2 grid
bwidth = 0.3
bheight = 0.3

# bottom left x, y positions of boxes
boxpositions = [
    (0, 0),
    (0 + 3.5 * bwidth, 0 - 3 * bheight),
    (0 + 3.5 * bwidth, 0 + 2 * bheight),
]

# numbers in boxes
boxnumbers = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [2, 3, 2, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
]

# draw boxes
for bpos, bnum in zip(boxpositions, boxnumbers):
    draw_2x2_grid(ax, bpos, bwidth=bwidth, bheight=bheight, numbers=bnum)

# draw arrows
draw_arrow(
    ax,
    (boxpositions[0][0] + 2 * bwidth, boxpositions[0][1] + bheight),
    (boxpositions[1][0], boxpositions[1][1] + bheight),
    textbelow="$t = 2$",
    textabove="$a_2(0)$",
    arrowkwargs={"color": "r", "head_width": 0.05, "length_includes_head": True, "lw": 2},
)

draw_arrow(
    ax,
    (boxpositions[0][0] + 2 * bwidth, boxpositions[0][1] + bheight),
    (boxpositions[2][0], boxpositions[2][1] + bheight),
    textbelow="$t = 1$",
    textabove="$a_1(1)$",
    arrowkwargs={"color": "k", "head_width": 0.05, "length_includes_head": True, "lw": 2},
)

ax.axis("equal")
ax.set_axis_off()

fig.show()
```

[image]

This is relatively complicated and there may be easier ways with [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) or the [ETEToolkit](http://etetoolkit.org/) (as suggested in the comments). Personally, I'd just make a plot like that in PowerPoint (or equivalent).